# SSRS purge rows from dbo.catalog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssrs-2012

We have a third party software that generates reports by adding a new "temp" report to the SSRS catalog every time a user prints a report so now the `dbo.catalog` table is almost 3 GB and has 16K+ rows worth of one time only reports.  Is there a way to safely purge these rows from this table?

To be clear, I am talking about ReportServer not ReportServerTempDB so EXEC FlushReportFromCache @Path and EXEC CleanExpiredCache are of no help.

From what I am reading online Microsoft does not want you messing with this table directly so there is little documentation.  I can't find any sort of official maintenance function that works on `dbo.catalog`.  I don't expect many people want to mass delete their reports so this does not surprise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and see if these temporary reports show up through the web service interface. You should be able to setup a powershell script to call the deleteitem web service method to delete the reports. 
That or unhide them in the report manager interface and manually delete them.
Those would be the supported ways to do it.

Comment: As well as calling the SSRS web service directly, there's a [Microsoft Powershell module](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools)

Comment: They show in the report server, there are so many of them that manual deletion is not an option plus they keep getting added to.  I have my DB blinders on so I didn't think about doing this via the web service, I will look into that.

Comment: cruciible - nice find. I'll be adding that to my bag of tricks along with the DBATools powershell module.

Comment: Vendor finally got back to me with a non-supported/documented solution.  Boss said use it so I went with it but from my initial research the web service idea was the most "Microsoft Supported" solution to my issue.